# Jquery .load function. Passing a php variable to .load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to pass a PHP variable, ($name) through the .load function. Every time i try to call similar.php, instead of search for whatever is in $name, its searching for

Heres my java code;

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("similar.php?search="+"&name");
  });
});
</script>
```

Ive also tried, orginally:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("similar.php?search=<?php $name ?>);
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to. But you make weird things in your code like `load('string'+'string')` or syntax error `load("string)`. And Java != JavaScript

Comment: sorry, the post about filtered out php tags. similar.php takes an argument, ie, similar.php?search=snoop%dog
snop%dog is stored in $name
im calling similar.php from video.php to display similar artists.
But when i attempt to call the above code(which you mentioned are both strings) which then returns a php page as a result, which would make sense.
So to review, what i need to do, is call the string, similar.php?search= followed by the variable $name
Can anyone, or you help me out please?

Comment: So, that should work `$("#div1").load("similar.php?search=<?php $name ?>");` Maybe it's all about that syntax error (missed `"`).

Comment: Oh, and type `echo` as at answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the last quote and to echo the `$name`, change this :

```
$("#div1").load("similar.php?search=<?php $name ?>);
```

to:

```
$("#div1").load("similar.php?search=<?php echo urlencode($name) ?>");
```

And use the DOM inspector to view the code and see that the PHP is outputted properly.

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesnt load anything, as can be seen here,
http://soundwavez.net/video/sVaRHJn_dgM

Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's because your URL is not valid, you need to URL encode the strings when there are spaces and special characters.

Comment: Well, going by what you said, ive removed the spaces, $("#div1").load("similar.php?search=<?$name?>");
and now its back to square one, returning a php related page. see the same link

Comment: The spaces are in your strings, you can't remove the echo and the spaces inside the php code, as that has nothing to do with it ?

Comment: oh im following you now!
So i'd have to call $name before the function, switch the space with % assign it to a new variable, then call the new variable?
You sir, are a genious, Thanks

Comment: You could do that, or just try urlencode to encode the string, like in my answer above. Of course, you have to catch this in $_GET on the serverside ?

Comment: My understanding of $_GET might be wrong, but if im encoding the string like above, so it will complete the string, why would i use $_get?
$_get catches string and passes the string to the http?
(I appreciate you help and i understand it must be fustrating trying to get me to undertsand, thanks!)

Comment: `similar.php` returns something based on the querystring passed, like `search=Robbie+Williams+-+She%27s+The+One"`, so inside `similar.php` you'd use `$_GET['search']` to get that string ?

Comment: Oh right, Im using $_REQUEST
if(isset($_REQUEST['search']) && !empty($_REQUEST['search'])) {
 //gets api and stuff

$_REQUEST is abit like $_GET and $_POST combined, so i thought it would do the same?

Comment: It does the same thing, so no problem!